# Thunderbird/Outlook if mail not received last 24 hours

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, cron

I have some routine emails that are sent every day, they are automatically going in some folders.

However, if I don't receive the mail in the last 24 hours I want to have an alert, in thunderbird or Outlook.

My idea was to create a script with a database that is run by a cron every hour. It checks if the mail arrived every day and if not I send an alert on our monitoring system.

Any idea if I can do it in a simpler way with an addon for example.
Thanks ahead for the help.

Comment: Is thunderbird/Outlook usage a requirement or can you explore command-line or scripted alternatives (like imapfilter) ?

Comment: @Uriel anything can work if it does what I want. I gonna look at what it is looks intressting is it able to filter it like I want?

Comment: Have you checked the scripts as I mentioned before?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar situation, according to my experience, it may need a custom add-in or VBA script to meet it in Outlook. Here is a related script about how to be reminded if a message does not arrive within a specified time, please check if it could also be helpful to you.
[Receive a Reminder When a Message Doesn't Arrive?](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-watch-updates/)